# How can I align a button at the bottom right in pyqt?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

I am using a vertical layout that contains a Qlistview on top and a button at the bottom. I am trying to add the button at the bottom right but it is positioned at the bottom left. I've tried  `self.verticalLayout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)` but I think that'd only work if the vlayout was part of a bigger layout.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use:

```py
self.verticalLayout.addWidget(your_button, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also use the binary or operator to combine multiple alignment rules if necessary.

```
self.verticalLayout.addWidget(your_button, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
```